# Iterate over lines in a string, including the newline characters

Tags: string, rust

I need to iterate over lines in a string, but keep the newlines at the end in the strings that are yielded.

There is [`str.lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines), but the strings it returns have the newline characters chopped off:

```
let result: Vec<_> = "foo\nbar\n".lines().collect();
assert_eq!(result, vec!["foo", "bar"]);
```

Here's what I need:

```
assert_eq!(lines("foo\nbar\n"), vec!["foo\n", "bar\n"]);
```

More test cases:

```
assert!(lines("").is_empty());
assert_eq!(lines("f"), vec!["f"]);
assert_eq!(lines("foo"), vec!["foo"]);
assert_eq!(lines("foo\n"), vec!["foo\n"]);
assert_eq!(lines("foo\nbar"), vec!["foo\n", "bar"]);
assert_eq!(lines("foo\r\nbar"), vec!["foo\r\n", "bar"]);
assert_eq!(lines("foo\r\nbar\r\n"), vec!["foo\r\n", "bar\r\n"]);
assert_eq!(lines("\nfoo"), vec!["\n", "foo"]);
assert_eq!(lines("\n\n\n"), vec!["\n", "\n", "\n"]);
```

I have a solution that basically calls `find` in a loop, but I'm wondering if there's something more elegant.

This is similar to [Split a string keeping the separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257273/split-a-string-keeping-the-separators), but in that case, the characters are returned as separate items, but I want to keep them as part of the string:

```
["hello\n", "world\n"]; // This
["hello", "\n", "world", "\n"]; // Not this
```

Answer (score 9):

The solution I currently have looks like this:

```
/// Iterator yielding every line in a string. The line includes newline character(s).
pub struct LinesWithEndings<'a> {
    input: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> LinesWithEndings<'a> {
    pub fn from(input: &'a str) -> LinesWithEndings<'a> {
        LinesWithEndings {
            input: input,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for LinesWithEndings<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        if self.input.is_empty() {
            return None;
        }
        let split = self.input.find('\n').map(|i| i + 1).unwrap_or(self.input.len());
        let (line, rest) = self.input.split_at(split);
        self.input = rest;
        Some(line)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `start` parameter if you use `slice::split_at` instead: then you can update `self.input` on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuM., that simplifies it!

Comment: There's now a `split_inclusive` associated function that does this https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.SplitInclusive.html. It was stabilized in 1.51.0

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty solution is this:

```rust
"foo\nbar\n".lines().map(|x| format!("{}\n", x.unwrap())).collect::<Vec<String>>()
```

This works, because the `format!` macro creates a new `String` for each line, just to include the newline. This is wasteful, and it should be much slower than robinst's solution. It also fails the provided assertions, because you get `String`s out of it instead of `&str`s

Comment: Hey! Yeah that works, but because of the `format!` call, allocates a new `String` object for each line unnecessarily which I avoided in my solution.

Comment: Thanks, good point, I should've said that. It's the reason why I called it "quick and dirty".

Answer (score 0):

There is now a beautiful approach, which is still feature-gated, but seems to make its way into `stable`.

Just add `.intersperse("\n")` right before `collect`ing the `lines`, and you're all set.

Note that atm (2023-03-19) it requires to add `#![feature(iter_intersperse)]` in the beginning of the crate root.

PS Actually it's answer to [How do I keep newlines when using lines() and collect() to return a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379972/how-do-i-keep-newlines-when-using-lines-and-collect-to-return-a-string) which is closed with the link to this one question. I feel like the answer still useful (though solves related issue instead of precise of this question). Maybe mighty moderators could reopen the linked question and move this answer there to keep things tidy.

Comment: Nit: Features don't go in the beginning of the file you use the feature in. They go in your crate root (i.e. usually your `lib.rs` or `bin.rs`)

Comment: Won't that produce `["hello", "\n", "world", "\n"]` instead of `["hello\n", "world\n"]`?

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues, thank you -- updated the answer. I should have double-checked it, but relied on my memory. (=

Comment: @robinst, exactly. That's how PS in the end was born. I actually got to this question from the one I linked (which is closed, unfortunately), and after adding the answer took a moment to read the open question again and find out that this helpful addition doesn't exactly solve **this** one problem.