# How do I keep newlines when using lines() and collect() to return a String?

Tags: string, rust

I  have a file called `a_file.txt` and i want to read it like so and filter out the string `"help me"` from each line in that file:

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let _s: String = std::fs::read_to_string("a_file.txt")?
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| line.contains("help me"))
        .map(|s| s.to_string())
        .collect();
    Ok(())
}
```

The `map` function here makes it so that `collect()` returns a `String` not a `&str`.

This code returns the text but it seems to have removed the `\n`. I assume this happens because the `lines()` function consumes the `\n` to make an iterator.

How do I retain the `\n`s? I want to remove the specified string from each line so I have to use the `lines()` function.

Comment: I am sorry, filter or filter out?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Iterate over lines in a string, including the newline characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40455997/155423) or [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36941851/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Or easy but bad solution ->  modify your map like this `.map(|s| s.to_string() + "\n")`

Comment: I'd use `.fold(String::new(), |s, l| s + l + "\n")` instead of `.map` and `.collect`.