# How do I split a string using a Rust regex and keep the delimiters?

Tags: regex, rust

I have a string that is separated by a delimiter. I want to split this string using regex and keep the delimiters.

My current code is:

```rust
use regex::Regex; // 1.1.8

fn main() {
    let seperator = Regex::new(r"([ ,.]+)").expect("Invalid regex");
    let splits: Vec<_> = seperator.split("this... is a, test").into_iter().collect();
    for split in splits {
        println!("\"{}\"", split);
    }
}
```

The output of which is:

```
"this"
"is"
"a"
"test"
```

I would like to keep the separators (in this case the space characters), the output I would like to see is:

```
"this"
"... "
"is"
" "
"a"
", "
"test"
```

How can I, if at all possible, achieve such behavior with [regex](https://docs.rs/regex/1.1.6/regex/)?

This is different from [Split a string keeping the separators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32257273/155423), which uses the standard library and not the regex crate.

Comment: why do you want keep them you know they are space.

Comment: The space is just an example. I will actually be matching other characters/sequences. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: The duplicate isn't an exact match, since it does not use the `regex` crate. I believe in this case your best option is to use `find_iter()` to either find all separators and their start and stop indices, or to extend the regex to [match either a separator or or the text between the separators](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cac108acfeb2a61a6c2293c47e8082c6). (I would add this as an answer, but it doesn't really fit for the dupe, so I'll leave it as comment.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach in the future, feel free to edit the question to make it a distinctly clear duplicate. You can also @-mention me directly if I did the closing / editing. It's reopened now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As documented on the [`Regex`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.1.9/regex/struct.Regex.html) type:

> ## Using the `std::str::pattern` methods with `Regex`
>
> > **Note**: This section requires that this crate is compiled with the
> >     `pattern` Cargo feature enabled, which **requires nightly Rust**.
>
> Since `Regex` implements `Pattern`, you can use regexes with methods
>   defined on `&str`. For example, `is_match`, `find`, `find_iter`
>   and `split` can be replaced with `str::contains`, `str::find`,
>   `str::match_indices` and `str::split`.

Using the `pattern` feature, you can use the techniques described in [Split a string keeping the separators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32257273/155423):

```
use regex::Regex; // 1.1.8

fn split_keep<'a>(r: &Regex, text: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    let mut last = 0;
    for (index, matched) in text.match_indices(r) {
        if last != index {
            result.push(&text[last..index]);
        }
        result.push(matched);
        last = index + matched.len();
    }
    if last < text.len() {
        result.push(&text[last..]);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let seperator = Regex::new(r"([ ,.]+)").expect("Invalid regex");
    let splits = split_keep(&seperator, "this... is a, test");
    for split in splits {
        println!("\"{}\"", split);
    }
}
```

This also gives you a hint on how to transform the code to not require nightly Rust:

> For example, [...] `find_iter` [...] can be replaced with [...] `str::match_indices`

Apply the reverse transformation to use stable `Regex` methods.

Comment: i'm getting `error[E0277]: expected a std::ops::Fn<(char,)> closure, found regex::re_unicode::Regex` in `split_keep` at `text.match_indices(r)` in rust 1.42.0-nightly and 1.40

Comment: @stuart to verify, did you follow the numerous warnings at the top of the answer about enabling the `pattern` feature?

Comment: ah, it works with this in `Cargo.toml` despite the flood of vscode warnings it triggers `regex = { version = "1.1.8", features = ["pattern"] }`